# Whirlpool ice maker making knocking noise, but still makes ice

Tags: repair

Ice maker is making ice but has started making a clicking noise.  I can see the two gears slipping and making the noise.  It is still making ice, but the noise is irritating.  Any suggestions how to fix this?  The gears do not look damaged.

Comment: What model is this unit?

Comment: Does it eject normally? You haven't made it clear *when* it clicks. Please edit your post to explain better and add model information.

Comment: My Whirlpool ice maker failed in 13 months ( after warrentee).. I fixed it by getting a Samsung refrigerator.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.  Web search just turned up retailers and drop shippers trying to sell me a new ice maker.

DO NOT ATTEMPT THIS KIND OF REPAIR UNLESS YOU ARE COMFORTABLE WITH WIRING ISSUES!!

There are several YouTube videos showing how to remove and replace the ice maker from the freezer.

What I discovered was a poor connection at the factory wire nut connecting the thermostat to the heating element.  This prevented the heating element from warming up fast enough to free the cubes before the ejection fingers hit the cubes.  Fingers could not move causing the gears to slip.  I simply removed the crimped wire nut, soldered the connection and replaced the wire nut with a twist on type.  Unit has worked great ever since.